# my audio isn't working on my pi-top

Tags: audio, pi-top

A few days ago i unplugged my speaker the put it back in, immediately the computer shut down and after restarting, worked perfectly. The next time i got on the audio was completely gone, and I've tried plugging in headphones I've tried turning up the volume. but it still is not working.

Comment: Have you checked that the audio is still set to the audio jack and not HDMI?

Comment: `after restarting, worked perfectly` .... how do you know? .... `seemed to be ok` is more appropriate

Comment: Have you checked the logfiles? I would start with `sudo grep -i audio /var/log/syslog`.